# Emberjs - Disable and Enable TextField

Tags: ember.js

So I've recently found the disabled attribute in the Em.TextField, however I can't seem to re-enable the TextField after I've extended it with the disabled property set to true.

```
var app = Em.Application.create();
app.randomObj = Em.Object.create({
    temp: null
});
app.textField = Em.TextField.extend({
    valueBinding: 'app.randomObj.temp',
    disabled: true
});
```

How do I remove the disabled property with Ember?

Comment: I am not sure what was back then when you posted this question, but it's definitely possible to define the disabled property within the view without any controller bindings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some issues with your sample code, I'll adress each one and hope I can clear some things up.

**Naming Convention**

First of all you should have a look at the Emberist post about [naming conventions](http://www.emberist.com/2012/04/09/naming-conventions.html): Classes should be named UpperCase and instances lowerCase - exception for applications and namespaces. So in your provided JSFiddle in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523780/emberjs-disable-and-enable-textfield#comment13617811_10525702) it's `App.controller` and `App.ATextField`.

**Declaring App as global variable**

You are creating an instance of an `Ember.Application` and assigning it to `var app`. Although you should be careful when using global variables, in this case you should define your application on the global namespace, so it should be `App = Ember.Application.create();` respectively `window.App = Ember.Application.create();`. By declaring the app as global variable, you can use the powerful **Bindings** feature in your templates and your JS code.

**Bindings**

The bindings should be declared on instances and not on classes. By this I mean you wouldn't define the `valueBinding` of your `App.TextField` in your class definition but rather move this to the concrete instance, for example in the template.

In your provided JSFiddle in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523780/emberjs-disable-and-enable-textfield#comment13617811_10525702) your binding to the controller does not work because you don't use one: to create a binding to a specific controller/object/... you'll have to declare the property name you want to bind to and append a `Binding` String. So it would be `disabledBinding: 'App.controller.shouldDisable'`.

---

**Example**

I've refactored your code, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/pLpKV/:

**Handlebars**:

```html
{{view Ember.TextField
    valueBinding="App.tempObj.hold"
    disabledBinding="App.controller.shouldDisable"}} {{App.tempObj.hold}}
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
App = Em.Application.create();

App.controller = Em.Object.create({
    shouldDisable: true
});

App.tempObj = Em.Object.create({
    hold: "initial value"
});

// just to illustrate how to define bindings outside of templates,
// we're adding a TextField with bindings setup the same as for the
// template
Ember.TextField.create({
    valueBinding: 'App.tempObj.hold',
    disabledBinding: 'App.controller.shouldDisable'
}).appendTo('body');
```

Comment: Wow, this is more than I could have hoped for.  Thanks for taking the time to actually explain my problems, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Bind it to a controller, and you can toggle it at will. Disabled is a bound attribute, so when the property changes, the template will update.

Comment: When I bind it to a controller I get something like this in the HTML    `<input id="ember157" class="ember-view ember-text-field" disabled="app.Controller.shouldDisable" type="text">`Edit: added a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RPWnX/)

Comment: You put binding paths in a separate property that ends in 'Binding,' 'disabledBinding' in this case.