# emberjs how to disable Ember.Select?

Tags: ember.js

i have a similar question to this question

[Emberjs - Disable and Enable TextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523780/emberjs-disable-and-enable-textfield)

so for text field it's disabledBinding.

what about Ember.Select (drop down field)?
i tried disabledBinding but it's not working.

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not working because `disabled` is not defined in `attributeBindings`, see [code](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/controls/select.js#L100).

A solution is to extend the `Ember.Select` and add `disabled` to the concatenated property* `attributeBindings`, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/wTXfH/:

**Handlebars**:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" >
    {{view App.Select disabled="true"}}
</script>​
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
App.Select = Ember.Select.extend({
    attributeBindings: ['disabled']
});​
```

---

*concatenated property means, that overwriting the this property in a subclass does not overwrite the values, but extends the existing ones from the super class.