# How to add "Disabled" attribute to options in Ember.Select

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js

I have a Ember.Select view, how would i add/bind a disabled attribute to the option tag (NOT the entire select box).

ie, i would love to accomplish the following result.

```
<select>
    <option value="1" disabled>I am a disabled option</option>
    <option value="2">Im selectable</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Does this help..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457206/emberjs-how-to-disable-ember-select

Comment: No unfortunately, that disables the entire select box. I want to disable just some of the options within the select box.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `Ember.Select` view doesn't do this out of the box. You will need to add a custom attribute binding for `disabled` and a corresponding computed property to tell Ember how to find it.

A simple approach is to add the disabled attribute on the content/data item used to render the select.

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  choices: function() {
    return [
      Ember.Object.create({firstName: "Lorem", id: 1}),
      Ember.Object.create({firstName: "Ipsum",    id: 2, disabled: true}),
      Ember.Object.create({firstName: "Dolor", id: 3}),
      Ember.Object.create({firstName: "Sit", id: 4}),
      Ember.Object.create({firstName: "Amet", id: 5})
    ];
  }.property()
});
```

and reopen or extend the `Ember.SelectOption` view adding the `disabled` attribute and computed property.

```
Ember.SelectOption.reopen({
  attributeBindings: ['value', 'selected', 'disabled'],

  disabled: function() {
    var content = this.get('content');
    return content.disabled || false;
  }.property('content'),

});
```

Here's a working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/oselog/2/). Note that the `ipsum` option is disabled.

Comment: Thank you. Hopefully this works its way into the core one day ;)

Comment: I like this approach, but any idea how one might pass in data-attributes that require hyphenated names?

Comment: I used `.property('content.disabled')` rather than .`property('content')`, but otherwise this works well.

Answer (score 2):

You can handle it in `didInsertElement` hook in your custom `Ember.Select` view..

```
didInsertElement: function () {
    this.$('option[value="1"]').attr('disabled', true);
}
```

Comment: not really the ember way. you should be binding handlebars attributes to your data instead.